# GreenMail Returning Multiple To Addresses

Tags: java, junit, greenmail

Running JUnit test cases utilizing GreenMail to do some basic email validation. I'm having issues when attempting to validate the *RecipientType.TO*. My JUnit assertion is failing - so I logged the message header, and it appears that the recipient is actually being set twice.

Here is a sample unit test that I'm running:

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

private GreenMail greenMail;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    // GreenMail config
    greenMail = new GreenMail(ServerSetupTest.SMTP);
    greenMail.start();
}

@Test
@DirtiesContext
public void testEmail() throws Exception {
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    String testFrom = "from@test.com";
    String testTo = "to@test.com";
    String testSubject = "Test Subject";
    String testText = "Test Text";

    message.setFrom(testFrom);
    message.setTo(testTo);
    message.setSubject(testSubject);
    message.setText(testText);
    mailSender.send(message);

    Message[] messages = greenMail.getReceivedMessages();
    assertEquals(1, messages.length);
    assertEquals(testSubject, messages[0].getSubject());
    assertEquals(testText, GreenMailUtil.getBody(messages[0]));
    assertEquals(testFrom, GreenMailUtil.getAddressList(messages[0].getFrom()));
    assertEquals(testTo, GreenMailUtil.getAddressList(messages[0].getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)));
}
```

I logged out the header and found that it contains two *RecipientType.TO* instances (Received, Message-ID, Date fields obfuscated):

```
 Return-Path: <from@test.com>
 Received: from localhost
 Date: 12345678
 From: from@test.com
 To: to@test.com
 To: to@test.com
 Message-ID: <----------->
 Subject: Test Subject
 MIME-Version: 1.0
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Any ideas on why the *To:* looks to be set twice?

I've found that not using the *GreenMailUtil.getAddresList()*, explicitly returning the recipients and examining the first element works, for example:

```
 Address[] recipientTo = messages[0].getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO);
 assertEquals(testTo, recipientTo[0].toString());
```

But I'd like to try and understand why GreenMail looks to be setting the recipient address twice.

Cheers!

## UPDATE

The above issue was run using GreenMail version 1.3.1b. As per suggestion of @Roland Weisleder updated to the latest version of GreenMail (1.5.3) and the same unit test runs as expected, setting the *TO* addressee only once.

Comment: I executed your unit test with GreenMail 1.5.3 (and test-dependencies from Spring Boot 1.5.2) and got just one To-header. What version of GreenMail do you use?

Comment: That did it - I was running version 1.3.1 previously. I updated to 1.5.3 and the _TO_ addressee is set the expected number of times. There must have been a bug in that version. Thanks!